# ExpressJS res.json({}) and res.render({}). How to pass values to EJS template using res.json({})

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, ejs

I'm new to Node and ExpressJS. I'm reading many tutorials but few things I'm unable to understand.

One of the tutorial I learnt while registering user.

```
router.post('/', function (req, res) {

    const data = req.body

    user = People(data)

    user.save(function (error) {        
        const emailValue    = data.email
        const phoneValue   = data.phone
        const name         = data.name

        if(error){
            const {email, phone} = error.errors
            res.render("register", { email, phone, name, emailValue, phoneValue } ); 
        }
        res.status(200).render("home", { name } );        
    });
```

The above code works as expected as I get all the values `email, phone, name, emailValue, phoneValue` in my EJS template engine.

However in another example. I have below code which work very well in **POSTMAN**

When I try to implement **UI** using EJS, I'm unable to pass/get these data in **UI**. The common error I get is `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning`

```
const register = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const {error} = validation.registerSchema.validate(req.body, {abortEarly: false});

    if (error) {
      res.status(400).json({
        status: 400,
        message: 'INPUT_ERRORS',
        errors: error.details,
        original: error._original,
      });
    } else {    

      // Create new User instance
      const user = new User({
        email: req.body.email,
        emailConfirmed: false,
        emailToken: uuidv4(),
        security: {
          tokens: [],
          passwordReset: {
            token: null,
            provisionalPassword: null,
            expiry: null,
          },
        },
      });

      // Attempt to save the user in database
      await user.save();

      res.status(200).header().json({
        success: {
          status: 200,
          message: 'REGISTER_SUCCESS',
          user: {
            id: user.id,
            email: user.email,
          },
        },
      });
    }
  } catch (error) {
    let errorMessage;

    if (error.keyPattern.email === 1) {
      errorMessage = 'EMAIL_EXISTS';
    } else {
      errorMessage = error;
    }

    res.status(400).json({error: {status: 400, message: errorMessage}});
  }
}
```

Comment: you just need to use `res.json({ success: { .... your json }})`. You do not need `.status(200)`. It's the default.

Comment: My question is how to pass these values to EJS template using res.json({})